# Making Android Layout Scrollable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scroll

I am developing an Android App inside Visual Studio and I cant figure out how to make it scroll.

I am posting my AXML pastebin link!

[AXML file](https://pastebin.com/VZnWy5nC)

Thank you

Comment: Put it inside a ScrollView.

Comment: i did that , but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your xml stuff inside a `ScrollView`. You should also change the `android:layout_height` of your root `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f0ffa0"
            android:scrollIndicators="right"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65.3dp"
            android:background="#aecc0a"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="48.3dp"
                android:layout_height="41.0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#aecc0a"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/backbutton"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/loginLabel1"
                android:layout_width="62.0dp"
                android:layout_height="24.0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="98dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="LOGIN"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="54.7dp"
                android:layout_height="42.7dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loginicon2"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="#414347"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="Button"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loginlabel3"
            android:layout_width="258.3dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="ENTER YOUR DETAILS"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="3.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#414347"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="Button"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loginLabel1"
            android:layout_width="148.3dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="CUSTOMER ID"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginCustID"
            android:layout_width="144.0dp"
            android:layout_height="37.0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:editable="true"
            android:hint="*Required"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:text="1234565432456"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loginLabel4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="PASSWORD"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
            android:layout_width="200.0dp"
            android:layout_height="37.0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:password="true"
            android:text="1234567890"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginSubmit"
            android:layout_width="140.5dp"
            android:layout_height="66.0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="#5dea4b"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#414347"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="Button"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="260.0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="230.3dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
                    android:text="* Customer ID is 8 digits long"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="italic"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="235.0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="* Password is 8-10 digits long"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="italic"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="2.7dp"
                android:layout_height="92.7dp"
                android:background="#414347"
                android:clickable="false"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="89.0dp"
                android:layout_height="78.0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#f0ffa0"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/easeofaccess"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```